# how to make a javascript not apply pagewide in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply a thirdparty script on my website. Here's the format below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thirdpartysite.com/front.asp?id=xxxx"></script>
```

In my Rails3 app, I want this script to be only applied on certain images contained within posts (only images/posts where value copyright==true). So I tried using it in this code:

```
<% if post.copyright == true %>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thirdpartysite.com/front.asp?id=xxxx"></script>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, this javascript affects ALL of the images on the pages. There are multiple posts per page and I am trying to individualize this javascript into each post.

Any ideas how I can get this to work? Can I get this to work using `<div id ="%=post.id" %>`, CSS selectors, or some way? (not really sure)

I do not have access to the source code of the javascript as it's from a third party site. I'm not able to customize it. All I have is this script code that they gave me and I thought that I would be able to apply it only to certain images/posts on my website.

Comment: that question doesn't have an answer that works. any ideas on how to get this to work without access to the 3rd party code, mu?

Comment: But they're really the same question. If the third party script doesn't have a documented interface then it is garbage and you should write your own; if it does have a documented interface then you should read it. You're basically asking us "how do I use this piece of JavaScript that I'm not going to show you or tell you where it is from?". You could probably kludge around it with `<iframe>`s but that's pure madness and I fell dirty for even thinking of it.

Answer (score 3):

The script will execute in the context of the entire document. It sounds like you're listing a bunch of posts on the page and including the same script multiple times depending on the logic; you would typically include the script just once.

You'll have to inspect the third party code (or their documentation) to see how it is selecting the images to manipulate. It may reveal a way to add a class to images or parent elements that allow you to filter out images you don't want manipulated.